# Javascript: Parameter is undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I recently began learning javascript, and this is the answer to a practice problem (Write a function that swaps the cases of each letter in a string):

```
var swapCase = function(letters){
    var newLetters = "";
    for(var i = 0; i<letters.length; i++){
        if(letters[i] === letters[i].toLowerCase()){
            newLetters += letters[i].toUpperCase();
        }else {
            newLetters += letters[i].toLowerCase();
        }
    }
    console.log(newLetters);
    return newLetters;
}

var text = "Life is 10% what happens to you, and 90% of how you REACT to it";
var swappedText = swapCase(text);
```

OUTPUT:

```
"lIFE IS 10% WHAT HAPPENS TO YOU, AND 90% OF HOW YOU react TO IT"
```

The code is perfectly functional and does exactly what it needs to do, but I am confused on the use of `letters`. This is not my code.

The parameter `letters` is not linked to anything anywhere, and this is what confuses me. I believe it represents each individual letter, but where is it defined to do so? I am familiar with Python, so I was expecting something like `for i in list`.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: WHats your question? WHenever you call the function **swapCase** letters is gonna be whatever you pass to it in parenthesis. swapCase(text) is just saying letters will be equal to **text**

Comment: when you put `text` in the parameter, `text` becomes `letters` inside the function

Comment: `letters` is placeholder/ argument that has been provided when you call `swapCase(text);`, so `text` becomes `letters` inside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put `text` in the parameter, `text` becomes `letters` inside the function.

```
var swapCase = function(letters){  //anything you put as a parameter in this function will become 'letters'
var newLetters = "";
for(var i = 0; i<letters.length; i++){
    if(letters[i] === letters[i].toLowerCase()){  //letters[i] represents the character in the 'i' position (which is assigned in the for loop) in the string you added as a parameter.
        newLetters += letters[i].toUpperCase();
    }else {
        newLetters += letters[i].toLowerCase();
    }
}
console.log(newLetters);
return newLetters;
}

var text = "Life is 10% what happens to you, and 90% of how you REACT to it";
var swappedText = swapCase(text); // You are adding the text string as a parameter in the function, thus it becoming the letter variable inside the function
```

Answer (score 2):

`letters` is a function parameter, so basically when you call swapCase(text), the function takes `text` and assign it to `letters`. If you call the function without parameter like this `swapCase()` then you basically pass `undefined` to this function and that is assign to `letter`. You can do a quick check at the beginning of the function to check for that.

```
if(letters === undefined) return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

> The parameter letters is not linked to anything anywhere

It is defined here — `function(letters){` — as an argument name on the function.

It is passed a value when the function is called here — `swapCase(text);` — where `text` is a variable defined as a string on the line above.

> I believe it represents each individual letter, but where is it defined to do so?

It's a string. You can access [characters in a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access) using square bracket notation.

Answer (score 1):

When you write the line of code `swapCase(text)` you are passing the variable `text` into the function `swapCase`.  The `letters` variable inside the function gets assigned the value of whatever `text` is.